# The directory "/tmp" does not have enough space for extraction

Tags: linux, debian

[Debian 7.7] Want to install jdeveloper. Moved the file jdev_suite_121300_linux64.bin (1.7Gb) to folder /opt/jdeveloper/. 
The

```
chmod +x jdev_suite_121300_linux64.bin
```

is applied.

Running the execute command gets the result

```
root@debian:/opt/jdeveloper# sudo ./jdev_suite_121300_linux64.bin 
** The directory "/tmp" does not have enough space for extraction.
Please input another directory or [Exit]:
```

Also

```
root@debian:/opt/jdeveloper# sudo mount -o remount,size=2560m /tmp
mount: can't find /tmp in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

root@debian:/opt/jdeveloper# df -h /tmp
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/debian-root  9.2G  7.2G  1.6G  83% /
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're out of hard disk space. (1.7G > 1.6G) Which is also probably the compressed size. Try putting the file on a different disk/partition or free up some space (e.g. by removing unnecessary files from `/tmp`).

*Edit:* On a related note, your `/tmp` is probably **not** a separately mounted disk, and will most likely be the same mounting point as `/`. Hence I do not see why you'd try to remount it or check the disk space.

Comment: And neither is `/opt`.  He probably could free up some space by moving the installer file to an external drive and running it from there.  But he's still critically low on disk space if he's wanting to install something that big and then actually use it.

Answer (score 1):

If /tmp is not big enough, then try this

./jdev_suite_121300_linux64.bin -J-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/jongunn/temp

Comment: will try, thx for answer